# passing git hub credentials in jenkins in form of token

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have created a Jenkins job in which my Source Code Management is GitHub.
And I am passing credentials to access it.

I am looking for an approach where I can use my GitHub credentials in a tokenized format.

[image: Jenkins UI]

Comment: I saw you removed the picture, but also that a moderator decided to put it back. I agree the picture is important, so I took the liberty to anonymize it.

Comment: Thanks VonC for your contribution. Accidentally I have updated my Clients info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Jenkins GitHub Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) should be enough to allow you to use your [GitHub PAT (Personnal Access Token)](https://github.com/settings/tokens) (provided you [did not activate 2FA](https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/) on your account)

[image: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/37749162/manage-token.png]

Comment: Actually, test it too if you have activated 2FA: a PAT should work in this case.